# Android Wear Wake Mobile

Tags: wear-os

**Edit**
I erased everything for clarity. as i am going to simplify my request for information:
What is best way to handle receiving messages from a wear on a mobile when the mobile is asleep or if app is not in the foreground?

During both these circumstances even though i send messages to the mobile from the wear, the mobile does not receive or process them. i do not know which.

if have read the following:
1) partial wakelocks - no good i dont want to really keep CPU awake
2) handler
3) broadcastreceiver
4) service

i do not know exactly what i should do in order to process messages with my app when app is not in the foreground and/or asleep.

If the onMessageReceieved() SHOULD process during sleep and or when app is not in foreground letting me know that would also be beneficial as right now i think it should not based on what i am seeing in my app.

Also i am using livelisteners instead of a listener service. is this my problem? if i instead switch to a wearablelistenerservice class will that solve my issues and work correctly? 
i do this

```
 @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connected to Google Api Service");
    }
    Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}
```

instead of if i do this:

```
public class DataLayerListenerService extends WearableListenerService{
```

and put all my codes in there and then do this:

```
<service android:name=".DataLayerListenerService">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
      <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*"
           android:path="/start-activity" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

will that solve my not receiving messages problem when not in foreground and when phone is asleep? as this intent will act as a service that runs in the background?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [Keeping the Device Awake](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) wherein it discussed different approaches that you can use such as [keeping the CPU on](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#cpu).

As mentioned,

> If you need to keep the CPU running in order to complete some work before the device goes to sleep, you can use a [`PowerManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) system service feature called wake locks. Wake locks allow your application to control the power state of the host device.

You may find more tips and information in the use of wake locks from the given [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#cpu).

Comment: I appreciate your answer, i did attempt that and tried to use the partial wakelock to keep the CPU awake. It was unsuccessful. plus highly ineffective considering i want to use this functionality once every 5-10 minutes and keeping a wakelock on waiting for that seems silly. I did more reading on wakelocks yesterday and attempted this.

Answer (score 0):

Using a class that extends WearableListenerService and adding service to manifest worked for working while phone is off. Now i just need to implement and interact into the main feed to update data on the main screen